# New Laravel install v 5.4 index.php throwing parsing error. PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

New Laravel install on Digital Ocean, Ubuntu.  Current PhP install.  Apache2 is accessing Php just fine as I added a couple lines of code to spit out errors.  This is the output:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /var/www/html/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 388

```
    public static function pluck($array, $value, $key = null)
{
    $results = [];
    [$value, $key] = static::explodePluckParameters($value, $key);
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $itemValue = data_get($item, $value);
        // If the key is "null", we will just append the value to the array and keep
        // looping. Otherwise we will key the array using the value of the key we
        // received from the developer. Then we'll return the final array form.
        if (is_null($key)) {
            $results[] = $itemValue;
        } else {
            $itemKey = data_get($item, $key);
            if (is_object($itemKey) && method_exists($itemKey, '__toString')) {
                $itemKey = (string) $itemKey;
            }
            $results[$itemKey] = $itemValue;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Line 888 is:

```
[$value, $key] = static::explodePluckParameters($value, $key);
```

Laravel automatically creates a key when creating a new site with "laravel new (site name)"

Server is running my other sites just fine.  I've done several clean Laravel installs, same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because the PHP that is evaluating this script is not version 7.2. It's a version lower than 7.1. Array destructuring assignment was introduced in 7.1 - https://wiki.php.net/rfc/short_list_syntax

You need to figure out which PHP versions are installed and exactly which one is executing the code.

Comment: Aha.  Current PHP version: 7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /var/www/html/foo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 388

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone.  So what you need to do is go to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled ls-l and see what php version is loaded.  "sudo a2dismod php7.0" to disable php7.0 mod and use "sudo a2enmod php7.2".  Restart apache2 with "systemctl restart apache2" and you should be good.